# Gerenciamento de Pacotes no R, como exportar e importar pacotes?

Tags: r, packages

Utilizo meus scripts em vários computadores e seguidamente deparo-me com erros referente a falta de pacotes e muitas vezes tais computadores não possuem acesso a internet, o que dificulta o acesso aos repositórios.

Além disto, quando preciso dar manutenção a "máquina" (formatar), seria interessante ter um backup dos pacotes instalados, isto, me pouparia tempo.

Sendo assim, gostaria de saber como posso gerenciar meus pacotes, exportar e importar pacotes no R?

Comment: Exportar de um computador em que já foi baixado? Algum motivo para não instalar direto dos repositórios no outro computador?

Comment: dê uma olhada no packrat: https://rstudio.github.io/packrat/

Comment: Obrigado pelas dicas!
Molx -  Sim dos pacotes já instalados e pensando em casos que de computadores sem conexão a internet, ou criar um backup de todos os pacotes instalados.

Daniel - Vou olhar e depois lhe deu um Feedback.

Comment: A Revolution Analytics tem o [Reproducible R Toolkit](http://projects.revolutionanalytics.com/documents/rrt/rrtpkgs/) que visa a portabilidade de ambiente, o único ponto é que utilizam o repositório deles  (o MRAN) e não o CRAN, se bem que mantêm uma sincronização periódica com o CRAN.

Comment: Daniel - o pacote pacote packrat é bacana!
Wilson -  vou verificar o Reproduclible R Toolkit... obrigado desde já!

Comment: Legal @Jean! Se conseguir usar, você poderia escrever uma resposta ensinando o básico, assim os próximos que pesquisarem já terão a resposta :)

Comment: Joia! Farei assim que terminar de testa-lo.  :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Olha uma forma muito simples é copiar o conteúdo da pasta `C:\Users\User\Documents\R\win-library\3.2`, ou no lugar de 3.2 sua versão do R e colar no novo computador que possui o R sem os pacotes, tendo cuidado com a compatibilidade da versão do R do computador de origem e de destino.

Outra forma e no seu script testar se possui os pacotes e se não tiver instalar-los, veja (neste caso necessita de internet):

```
 #lista dos pacotes necessários no seu script
list.of.packages <- c("hydroTSM", "lubridate",'openxlsx')

# encontra novos pacotes no pc
new.packages <- list.of.packages[!(list.of.packages %in% installed.packages()[,"Package"])] 

# instala todos eles
if(length(new.packages)) install.packages(new.packages)
```