# Como instalar o pacote rgeos no R?

Tags: r, instalador

Estou tentando instalar o pacote rgeos no R e meu sistema operacional é o Windows 7. Usei o comando `install.packages('rgeos', type="source")` e me aparece a seguinte mensagem:

```
installing package into ‘C:/Users/Cloves/Documents/R/win-library/3.2’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/rgeos_0.3-19.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 252533 bytes (246 KB)
downloaded 246 KB

* installing *source* package 'rgeos' ...
** package 'rgeos' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

   **********************************************
   WARNING: this package has a configure script
         It probably needs manual configuration
   **********************************************


** libs
Warning: execução do comando 'make -f "Makevars.win" -f "C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-32~1.2/etc/i386/Makeconf" -f "C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-32~1.2/share/make/winshlib.mk" SHLIB_LDFLAGS='$(SHLIB_CXXLDFLAGS)' SHLIB_LD='$(SHLIB_CXXLD)' SHLIB="rgeos.dll" OBJECTS="dummy.o init.o local_stubs.o rgeos.o rgeos_R2geos.o rgeos_R2geosMP.o rgeos_bbox.o rgeos_buffer.o rgeos_coord.o rgeos_geos2R.o rgeos_misc.o rgeos_poly2nb.o rgeos_predicate_binary.o rgeos_predicate_unary.o rgeos_topology.o rgeos_topology_binary.o rgeos_validate.o rgeos_wkt.o"' teve status 127
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'rgeos'
* removing 'C:/Users/Cloves/Documents/R/win-library/3.2/rgeos'
Warning in install.packages :
  running command '"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-32~1.2/bin/i386/R" CMD INSTALL -l "C:\Users\Cloves\Documents\R\win-library\3.2" C:\Users\Cloves\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmp44In2b/downloaded_packages/rgeos_0.3-19.tar.gz' had status 1
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘rgeos’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘C:\Users\Cloves\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmp44In2b\downloaded_packages
```

Já existe uma pasta rgeos instalada dentro da pasta do R:[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Mas mesmo assim ao chamar esta biblioteca pelo comando `library(rgeos)` me aparece a mensagem dizendo que não existe esse pacote:

```
Error in library(rgeos) : there is no package called ‘rgeos’
```

Comment: já tentou instalar assim: `install.packages('rgeos')`. Acabei de instalar no windows 8 e no linux sem nenhum problema.

Comment: Tenta abrir o cmd como administrador, deu erro no make, talvez seja por falta de permissão

Comment: Sim, já tentei e não funcionou.

Comment: Entrei como administrador e ao tentar instalar me apareceu a mensagem:  "installation of package ‘rgeos’ had non-zero exit status"

Comment: Deu o mesmo erro quando tentou da forma que o Daniel sugeriu, ou foi outro problema?

Comment: Eu havia entrado no R como administrador e não deu certo agora tentei novamente entrando como administrador no RStudio e agora deu certo. Valeu pela atenção pessoal!

Comment: Fiz um busca sobre este erro mas não tive sucesso. Minha sugestão é que faça um backup dos seus dados e  atualize sua versão do R após isto reinstale seus pacotes. Dê uma olhada nestes dois tópicos: i) http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/107075/27863; ii) http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/121550/27863

Comment: O ideal era fechar esta questão...

Comment: @ClovesAdriano, favor marcar que a sua resposta "já foi respondida", fechar ela, ou mesmo responder ela no campo apropriado. para que ela não apareça mais como 'não respondida'. Isso ajuda a todos que já te ajudaram :D obrigado!!